# How to animate the button extend form all directions?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I make an animation to button in pyqt5. When I click on the button the button only extend from only two directions like the first image and I want the button to extend from all four directions like the second image

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.b = QPushButton('click', self)
        self.b.resize(50, 50)
        self.b.move(150, 150)
        self.b.clicked.connect(self.one)

    def one(self):
        self.an1 = QPropertyAnimation(self.b, b'size')
        self.an1.setStartValue(self.b.size())
        self.an1.setEndValue(QSize(100, 100))
        self.an1.setDuration(200)
        self.an1.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mai = main()
    mai.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only changing the size but not the position so you have the following options:

- Use the valueChanged signal to obtain the current size and recalculate the position.
- Create one more animation that changes the position depending on the size and that is silmutation with the other animation.
- Set the animation on the geometry instead of the size.

In this case I will show for the third option:

```py
def one(self):
    rect_start = QRect(self.b.geometry())
    rect_end = QRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
    rect_end.moveCenter(rect_start.center())

    an1 = QPropertyAnimation(self.b, b"geometry", self)
    an1.setStartValue(rect_start)
    an1.setEndValue(rect_end)
    an1.setDuration(200)
    an1.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
```

Comment: thanks a lot... Can you explain why you used (QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped) as an argument with start() ?